# SuspendLayouts, resumeLayouts and grid columns

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I use these two functions `suspendLayouts` and `resumeLayouts` in order to optimize large grid rendering. In particular, I use them just before and after I hide programmatically some grid columns. I do it like this:

```
Ext.suspendLayouts();

... a lot of code, some code may hide a lot of grid columns

Ext.resumeLayouts();
```

If I do not use them, browser either does not respond or responds with an alert about a long lasting script. If I use them, then it runs quite quickly, but not in all browsers. For example, in Chrome I see some columns do not get hidden, while their column titles/headers hide.

In small grids with a relatively small amount of columns, this code without suspending and resuming layouts works nice. But I need it to work in large grids.

By the way, I hide columns like this

```
var cols=grid.headerCt.getGridColumns()
Ext.each(cols, function (item, index, all){
  ... some code
  if(ok) item.setVisible(false);
})
```

Probably, there is another better way of hiding grid columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. I should have used `grid.suspendLayouts()` and `grid.resumeLayouts()` instead of `Ext.suspendLayouts()` and `Ext.resumeLayouts()`. Now, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Ext.suspendLayouts() didn't worked for me. Grid is still very slowly redrawn.
I used grid.reconfigure():

```
Ext.each(grid.initialConfig.columns, function (columnCo, index, all){
  ... some code
  if(ok) columnConfig.hidden = false;
})

grid.reconfigure(grid.store, grid.initialConfig.columns);
```

Comment: I also said in my answer, that I do not use `Ext.suspendLayouts()`. Instead I use `grid.suspendLayouts()`.